# Classified Nested Category->Sub Category->Post View for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am really working hard to get a specific Post view in my Wordpress blog.

Example

Click      http://theunlockr.com/roms/

Then Click http://theunlockr.com/roms/android-roms/

Then CLick http://theunlockr.com/roms/android-roms/asus-roms/

I figured that this is a  nested view of categories and subcategories and finally the post in the respective category.

Need some input on how to do this on a basic wordpress blog.

I have already tried page builder and Grid views and alot of plugins, but cant really make this kind of view.

Answer (score 2):

This is done via [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

For example, you could create a custom post type `rom`, and assign the custom taxonomy `roms` with child categories `Android ROMs -> Asus ROMs`. This child category is assigned to the custom post type.

Comment: i have done it. but the problem is that i am actually not able to creat this kin d of view !